# How to launch grunt automatically from webserver

Tags: gruntjs

I want to deploy a nodejs application.
This app comes with a Gruntfile.js file.
I have to run grunt command in order to launch my application in background.
I have setup an nginx web server with a proxypass configuration.
Everything works.

But, if i kill grunt process, the application stop.
What should i do in order to run properly this grunt command ?
Is there a way for nginx to automatically start this app in case of crash ?

Thanks

Comment: What is the reason to run your application using grunt? Grunt is actually a tasks runner and it's not designed for a long running processes.

Comment: it is an open source software (mosaico). What is the best way to run this process ? running app.js ?

Comment: Yes, you can try to use pm2 and run your application directly.

Comment: how can i see in gruntfile which main js file is launched ? I see many things in this file. When i try to launch manually app.js i have an error saying jquery module is missing